# Why is $F(u^{1/e})/F$ unramified?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

I'm reading a proof of Kronecker-Weber theorem, but I don't know a step in the proof of the below proposition:

> **Prop.** Let p be a prime number, $K/\mathbb Q_p$ be a cyclic extension of degree $l^r$ for some prime $l\neq p$, Then $K\subset \mathbb Q_p(\zeta_m) $ for some $m\in \mathbb Z.$

**Proof.**(I only quote the part related to my question.)

Let F be the maximal unramified extension of $\mathbb Q_p$ in $K$; then $F$ is cyclotomic, by (a Corollary in the text manual), so $F=\mathbb Q_p(\zeta_n)$. The extension $K/F$ is totally ramified, and it must be tamely ramified, since the ramification index is necessarily a power of $l$ and therefore not divisible by $p$. By (a Theorem in the text manual), we have $K=F(\pi^{1/e})$ for some uniformizer $\pi$ of the discrete valuation ring $O_F$, with $e = [K:F]$. We may assume that $\pi = -pu$ for some $u\in O^{\times}_F$, since $F/\mathbb Q_p$ is unramified.

> The extension $F(u^{1/e})/F$ is unramified, since $p\nmid e$ and $u$ is a unit. (the discriminant of $x^e-u$ is not divisible by $p$.)

**Why is the second highlighted statement true?**

I know a theorem that ramified primes are those divide the discriminant ideal, but $x^e-u$ seems to  be required to be irreducible to apply anything I know, but I'm not sure if it's irreduclble or not.

Comment: from which book you quote the proof?

Answer (score 4):

The discriminant of the polynomial $x^e-u$ is $\pm u^{e-1} e^e$, which is a unit, so the extension $F(u^{1/e})/F$ is unramified. This still works if $x^e-u$ is not irreducible, because its **field discriminant** must be a divisor of $\pm u^{e-1} e^e$.

Another approach to see $F(u^{1/e})/F$ is unramified is to check $x^e-u=0$ has distinct roots in the residual field of $F$, this is evident because $p\nmid e$.

Comment: Why in the second approach distinct roots implies unramified?

Comment: Here is a general fact: if $F$ is a complete discrete-valuated field, $\alpha$ satisfies a monic polynomial $f \in F[x]$ such that $f$ has distinct roots in the residual field of $F$, then $F(\alpha)/F$ is unramified.